# connecting 2 BLE Device together

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to connect 2 Nrf51822 device to each other, as Ad and scanner. 
but I want to have a full-duplex communication between them.
for example UARTconsole Application in MBED , mobile app can send and recieve from nrf but I want to use another board for mobile app.

Comment: Can you show some code examples? What have you tried so far? What is your programming platform?

Comment: I use mbed.org examples. 
[link] (https://developer.mbed.org/teams/Bluetooth-Low-Energy/code/BLE_UARTConsole/file/5f0732aa3008/main.cpp)

Comment: but this program work with android App for send and receive. nrf Control panel. 
I want a source code that do for me the duty of this android app.

Comment: So what is the error you encounter?

Comment: I want to have a uart communication between 2 nrf board. not a board and a mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I solved this problem by here:

[link](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/tutorials/21/)